# Area of triangle constructed from medians

Tags: geometry

> Area of triangle $LMN=72$
>   $LD, ME,NF$ are medians of $LMN$
>   Triangle $PQR$ is constructed such that $PQ=LD, QR=ME, PR=NF$
>   Find area $PQR$

I have not understood what really has to do in it please help me

Comment: A picture would be very helpful.

Comment: I haven't understood anything please help me

Comment: Anyone please help me

Comment: I'm not very close to an answer, but if you need the problem explained better: You have a triangle, points L,M,N.  All you are told is that it has an area of 72.  Now mark the midpoints of the triangle edges.  Point E is the midpoint of LN; D is the midpoint of NM; F is the midpoint of LM.  So now draw three segments: LD, ME, and NF.  What they then do is take these three segments and make a new triangle out of them.  That is, they make a new triangle out of PQ, which has the same length as LD, etc.  And then they want the area of the new triangle.  I'll try to think on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triangle Area Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186392/triangle-area-question)

Comment: I have got till that but what next

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/MedianTriangle.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [medial triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_triangle) drawn (in purple) between the midpoints of the original triangle (red) side midpoints - the feet of the medians (blue).

[image]

The medial triangle cuts the original triangle into four similar triangles, each with $1/4$ the area. Add three more of these triangles onto one side as shown, and draw parallel copies of two of the medians, shown in light blue, through those extra medial-sized triangles. Now the triangle of medians is complete and its area is half of six copies of the medial triangle, $6/2\cdot 1/4 = 3/4$ of the area of the original triangle.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to know that the medians cut the triangle into six equal-area pieces, and that each median cuts the other two medians in the ratio 2:1.

Take two of these pieces along one edge and turn one of them on the edge midpoint by 180°. Now you have a triangle that $1/3$ the area of the original and with sides that are all parallel to the medians and $2/3$ their length.

[image]

Scale this triangle up by $3/2$ and you have sides equal to the medians, and the area scales by $(3/2)^2 = 9/4$, so is now $9/4 \times 1/3 = 3/4$ of the area of the original triangle. In this case $3/4 \times 72 = 54$.